# Compiling JavaScript files in Angular 5 CLI project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, tsconfig

I have a problem compiling (including) JavaScript files in Angular 5.0.0 CLI project.

I am performing the following steps:

- Create an empty CLI (1.6.2) project (ng new test2). The project runs fine.
- Modify tsconfig.json to include the line *allowJs": true,* to compile/bundle Javascript files
- Create a simple Javascript file (eg test.js with content i=1;) in the app folder.
- Build fails in Angular 5 with the error below.

Angular 5 error

```
"ERROR in error TS5055: Cannot write file 
'/Users/user/Documents/workspace/test2/src/app/test.js' because it would 
overwrite input file.  Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize 
projects that contain both TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at 
https://aka.ms/tsconfig."
```

In Angular 4 JS file is compiled to the output directory specified in the outDir parameter and included in the final bundle.

ng --version is giving the following:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.2
Node: 6.10.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.2
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

outDir is set to "./dist/out-tsc" in tsconfig.json and "../out-tsc/app" in tsconfig.app.json.

Any thoughts anyone. 
Regards 
Dave

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue recently and am happy to report that I think I have a solution!

To start:

1. Upgrade your Angular to the latest version (`5.1`).
2. Upgrade your TypeScript to the latest supported version (`4.*`, as of the time of the writing -- not `5.*`)
3. You probably need `allowJs: true` in your config file.

Run `ng serve --aot` or `ng build --watch=auto --aot` You should see the above error and be unable to access your site.

Open one of the .ts file that's part of your app and make a small change (such as adding a single space) and then save the file.

Your app should compile!

(The `--watch=auto` and `--aot` flags are critical for this workaround, as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 0):

The error is present in the provided error message.

> "ERROR in error TS5055: **Cannot write file `'**/*.js'` because it would 
>   overwrite input file.**  Adding a tsconfig.json file will help organize 
>   projects that contain both TypeScript and JavaScript files. Learn more at 
>   https://aka.ms/tsconfig."

It appears that your build process is trying to compile `*.ts` files to `*.js` files, but cannot write the file because the file already exists.

Before your build process, simply clear out the build files from your distributable directory first.

---

**Advice**
It seems that you are dumping the `*.js` files directly in your `src/`, which can be messy and undesirable.

A better solution is to generate a `/dist` directory that contains the compiled build files.

Answer (score 0):

Ive raised a bug for this against the angular cli 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8991#issuecomment-353889755 that is being fixed in [PR8930](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/8930)